# What the strange memory leak with NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I noticed some strange of memory leaks when using NSData. 
Just create a simple project and add my code in it. 
I use some big JPEG file F8F32F0F-EC04-414D-9E67-518F8B1F598D.jpg. It is about 4.5 Mb. Here is a code:

```
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_NAME "com.example.syncqueue"

@implementation MySimpleViewController {
    dispatch_queue_t _backgroundQueue;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create(DISPATCH_QUEUE_NAME, NULL);
    dispatch_async(_backgroundQueue, ^(void) {

        while (true) {
            NSString *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
            path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"F8F32F0F-EC04-414D-9E67-518F8B1F598D.jpg"];

            [self uploadDocumentWithPath:path];

            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];
        }

    });
}

- (void)uploadDocumentWithPath:(NSString*)path
{
    NSLog(@"> uploadDocumentWithPath: %@", path);

    NSData* httpBody = [self createBodyWithPaths:@[path]];
    httpBody = nil;

    NSLog(@"< uploadDocumentWithPath");

    return nil;
}

- (NSData*)createBodyWithPaths:(NSArray *)paths
{
    NSMutableData *httpBody = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"paths counts: %d", [paths count]);

    for (NSString *path in paths) {
        NSData   *data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

        NSLog(@"data size: %lu", (unsigned long)[data length]);

        [httpBody appendData:[@"some data 1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; <---!!!
        [httpBody appendData:data];
        [httpBody appendData:[@"some data 2" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        data = nil;
    }

    return httpBody;
}
```

It is reproduced on both of my devices iPhone 4 witn iOS 7.1.2 and on iPhone 5 with iOS 8.4

Following is an interesting notices that I found from the study of the problem:

If you remove the following line, the problem is disappeared:

```
[httpBody appendData:[@"some data 1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

It is also not reproduced if I remove `for ()` clause from `createBodyWithPaths` method:

```
- (NSData*)createBodyWithPaths:(NSArray *)paths
{
    NSMutableData *httpBody = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"paths counts: %d", [paths count]);

    //for (NSString *path in paths) {
        NSData   *data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:paths[0]];

        NSLog(@"data size: %lu", (unsigned long)[data length]);

        [httpBody appendData:[@"some data 1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; <---!!!
        [httpBody appendData:data];
        [httpBody appendData:[@"some data 2" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        data = nil;
    //}

    return httpBody;
}
```

Every step on the graph on the following image is a loop iteration.

I know how to fix it problem in my project, I will remove for-clause because I need to attach only one file. But it is interesting the nature of the problem.

[image: Memory usage graph]

Comment: This code has scoping conufsion that makes it hard to follow what you're talking about. Please present a [complete and runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem you see.

Comment: Have you tried data = nil after appending to httpbody ?

Comment: To Angel Vasa. Yes, I wrote that I tried tricks with = nill in several ways. I doesn't helped.

Comment: To Josh Caswell. I will prepare more detailed code example.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I redesigned code example that is producing the problem. It is now clear to reproduce it by yourself.